# MySQL pivoting column names based on column values?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data like:

```
ID1   F1.   F2.   F3
X1. Enabled. Disabled. Disabled
X2. Disabled. Enabled. Enabled.
```

I'd like to get it into the form of:

```
ID1  Fields
X1.  F1
X2.  F2,F3
```

But I'm having writers block on how to approach the problem. Is this something a pivot would help with? Self-joining the table? I've tried some group_concat() aggregations on if() statements to no avail, similarly with grouping on case whens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID1, CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(F1,'Disabled'), NULLIF(F2,'Disabled'), NULLIF(F3,'Disabled')) AS Fields
FROM ...
```

See:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif

Comment: I wound up using a `if(F1 = 'Enabled','F1',NULL), ... ` instead of the NULLIF() but this was helpful!